# C++ circular buffer that guarantees contiguous data

Tags: c++, c++17, circular-list

For interfacing with C-API that requires data in one contiguous block
I came up with the following, which seems to work nicely, but I wanted
to see if I didn't miss anything crucial. Drawback is of course the reserved
size, which is double - but fine within my use cases.

Requirements for the ring buffer:

- **access to data in one contiguous block always guaranteed**
- pushing back of one or more elements

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

  template <typename T, size_t N>
  class ContiguousRingBuffer
  {
  public:
    using const_iterator = std::array<T, N*2-1>::const_iterator;
    using iterator = std::array<T, N*2-1>::iterator;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ContiguousRingBuffer() = default;
    ContiguousRingBuffer(ContiguousRingBuffer&& o) = default;
    ContiguousRingBuffer(ContiguousRingBuffer const&) = default;

    /// Iterator pair constructor.
    template <typename It>
    ContiguousRingBuffer(It beg, It end)
    {
      using from_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
      using to_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
      static_assert(std::is_nothrow_convertible_v<from_value_type, to_value_type>,
                    "from value type must be convertible to buffer type.");

      if (static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(beg, end)) > N) {
        m_end = std::copy(std::prev(end, N), end, m_data.begin());
      }
      else {
        m_end = std::copy(beg, end, m_data.begin());
      }
    }

    /// Initialize from any other ContinguousBuffer<S, M>
    template <typename S, size_t M>
    ContiguousRingBuffer(ContiguousRingBuffer<S, M> const& o)
      : ContiguousRingBuffer(o.cbegin(), o.cend())
    {}

    /// Initializer list constructor.
    ContiguousRingBuffer(std::initializer_list<T> init)
      : ContiguousRingBuffer(init.begin(), init.end())
    {}

    ContiguousRingBuffer& operator=(ContiguousRingBuffer&&) = default;
    ContiguousRingBuffer& operator=(ContiguousRingBuffer const&) = default;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    iterator begin() { return m_beg; }
    iterator end() { return m_end; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return m_beg; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return m_end; }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T& operator[](size_t pos) { return *std::next(m_beg, pos); }
    T const& operator[](size_t pos) const { return *std::next(m_beg, pos); }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constexpr size_t size() const { return std::distance(m_beg, m_end); }
    constexpr auto capacity() const { return N; }
    T* data() { return &(*m_beg); }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { m_beg = m_end = m_data.begin(); }
    bool is_empty() const { return size() == 0; }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void pop_back()
    {
      if (m_beg != m_end) {
        --m_end;
      }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void pop_back(size_t num_elements)
    {
      if (num_elements < size()) {
        m_end = std::prev(m_end, num_elements);
      }
      else {
        clear();
      }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_back(T&& value)
    {
      if (m_end != m_data.end())
      {
        *(m_end++) = std::forward<T>(value);
        if (size() > N) { ++m_beg; }
      }
      else
      {
        std::swap(m_beg, m_end);
        *(m_end++) = std::forward<T>(value);
        m_beg = m_data.begin();
        std::copy(m_end, m_data.end(), m_beg);
      }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    template <typename It>
    void push_back(It beg, It end)
    {
      using from_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
      using to_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
      static_assert(std::is_nothrow_convertible_v<from_value_type, to_value_type>,
                    "from value type must be convertible to buffer type.");

      // If inserted size is equal or larger than N, just copy the last N
      // elements of the range and reset m_beg and m_end
      const auto s = std::distance(beg, end);
      if (static_cast<size_t>(s) >= N)
      {
        std::copy(std::prev(end, N), end, m_data.begin());
        m_beg = m_data.begin();
        m_end = std::next(m_beg, N);
        return;
      }

      const auto space_left = std::distance(m_data.begin(), m_beg);
      const auto sz = std::distance(m_beg, m_end);

      // Check if there is enough space to copy/append the elements at the end
      if (static_cast<size_t>(s) <= 2*N - space_left - 1 - sz)
      {
        m_end = std::copy(beg, end, m_end);
        if (static_cast<size_t>(sz+s) > N) {
          m_beg = std::prev(m_end, N);
        }
        return;
      }

      m_beg = m_data.begin();
      m_end = std::copy(std::prev(m_end, N-s), m_end, m_data.begin());
      m_end = std::copy(beg, end, m_end);
    }

  private:
    std::array<T, N*2-1> m_data;
    iterator m_beg = m_data.begin();
    iterator m_end = m_beg;
  };
```

Comment: If it's contiguous it's not circular, almost by definition.

Comment: @MarkRansom I see your point - when the buffer becomes full, it starts removing elements at the start. In that sense it’s a ring buffer - I agree the interface is not a typical ring buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Design review

The basic idea isn’t bad if you really need a single, contiguous view of the ring buffer’s contents at all times. I’ve never seen a case where that’s actually necessary—whenever I’ve used a ring buffer that needed to be contiguous, such as in audio code, it’s always been fine to view it as two contiguous chunks—but if your case requires it, sure. The cost is the extra memory—more than double the usual—and the need to occasionally move the whole thing back, but, again, if you really need it, then that cost is probably acceptable.

There are a couple of problems with the way you’ve chosen to implement it, though, mostly stemming from the fact that you’re using an array of `T` under the hood.

### A broken abstraction

Before I get to that, though, there is a bit of weirdness in your ring buffer’s interface. *Normally*, a ring buffer is, basically, a queue: first in, first out (FIFO). The idea is that you push to the end of the buffer, and pop from the start, so if your pushes and pops are equally interleaved, then the contents of the buffer are continuously changing, always holding the newest data. Visually, that looks like this:

```
(This buffer is 8 items large. Dots indicate empty slots.)

At the start:           ........
After pushing 4 times:  ABCD....
After popping 2 times:  ..CD....
After pushing 4 times:  ..CDEFGH
After popping 1 time:   ...DEFGH
After pushing 1 time:   I..DEFGH
After popping 2 times:  I....FGH
AFter pushing 2 times:  IJK..FGH
After popping 2 times:  IJK....H
AFter pushing 2 times:  IJKLM..H
After popping 2 times:  .JKLM...
AFter pushing 2 times:  .JKLMNO.
After popping 2 times:  ...LMNO.
AFter pushing 2 times:  Q..LMNOP
```

You can see how once the pushing and popping settles into an equilibrium of two-and-two at a time, you get a sliding view of 4–6 letters that works its way through the alphabet. That’s the point of a ring buffer: it always contains the most recently added items.

Your class, however, only has pushes *and pops* at the end. That’s first in, *last* out (FILO; or last in, first out: LIFO… same difference). That’s a *stack*.

With the same operations, this is what your class’s data looks like:

```
At the start:           ........
After pushing 4 times:  ABCD....
After popping 2 times:  AB......
After pushing 4 times:  ABEFGH..
After popping 1 time:   ABEFG...
After pushing 1 time:   ABEFGI..
After popping 2 times:  ABEF....
AFter pushing 2 times:  ABEFJK..
After popping 2 times:  ABEF....
AFter pushing 2 times:  ABEFLM..
After popping 2 times:  ABEF....
AFter pushing 2 times:  ABEFNO..
After popping 2 times:  ABEF....
AFter pushing 2 times:  ABEFPQ..
```

You can see that:

1. The buffer *doesn’t* contain the 4–6 most recently pushed items. Rather, once things settle, the first 4 items remain untouched, and only the last two keep getting removed/replaced.
2. Because the buffer is never full, the last few slots never get touched.

When your buffer *does* become full, only then does it start eating elements at the start. So in that sense… yeah, it’s a ring buffer. In other words, your class only acts like a ring buffer *if you never pop*. So long as you keep pushing elements, you’ll eventually fill up the buffer and start dropping the oldest stuff, as a ring buffer should. The moment you try to remove anything, it breaks the abstraction.

A ring buffer interface only needs `push()` (which acts like `push_back()`) and `pop()` (which acts like `pop_front()`). If you want to add `push_front()` and/or `pop_back()`… then it’s not really a ring buffer any more, it’s more like a “circular deque”.

For an interface that better suits the ring buffer abstraction:

- You just need `push()` and `pop()`.
- You might want to have `emplace()`, too, as a smarter `push()`.
- *Maybe* a `try_push()` (and `try_emplace()`) that only pushes if there’s room. And if `pop()` throws an error or UB when the buffer is empty, then a `try_pop()` as well.
- If you want to be API compatible with standard containers like `std::deque` and `std::list` (and *only* those), then you could *also* have `push_back()` and `pop_front()` just as aliases for `push()` and `pop()` (and `emplace_back()`, too).
- `pop_back()` might have *some* use, I guess; there may be situations where you might want to cancel/replace the most recently added items. But it would probably be better named `remove_last()` and `replace_last()`. `pop_back()` could be an alias for `remove_last()`.

### `size()` lies

Suppose I create this very simple type:

```
struct object_t
{
    static std::size_t count;

    object_t() noexcept { ++count; }
    object_t(object_t const&) noexcept { ++count; }
    object_t(object_t&&) noexcept { ++count; }
    ~object_t() { --count; }

    auto operator=(object_t const&) noexcept -> object_t& = default;
    auto operator=(object_t&&) noexcept -> object_t& = default;
};

std::size_t object_t::count = 0;
```

And then I put in your ring buffer, and while trying to debug a complex program, I notice this behaviour:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    ContiguousRingBuffer<object_t, 10> buf;
    
    std::cout << "size of buffer:    " << buf.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << "number of objects: " << object_t::count << '\n';
}

// output:
//  size of buffer:    0
//  number of objects: 19
```

Now… something is very wrong. Something is broken and lying to me. Either there really are no objects in the buffer, and there’s some bug causing `object_t::count` to be incorrect… or there *are* 19 objects in the buffer, and `buf.size()` is giving the wrong number for some reason.

Since the code above is so trivial, the answer is obvious. But in a real-world, complex program, this could be an **ABSOLUTELY INFURIATING** debugging issue.

It gets worse. More on that in a moment.

The root issue here is that you’re using a `std::array<T, (2 * N) - 1>` internally, so the moment I instantiate `ContiguousRingBuffer<object_t, 10>`, there are \$( 2 \times 10 ) - 1 = 19\$ default-constructed instantiations of `object_t`… *even while the buffer claims to be empty*. But the *real* problem is that *your class is lying to me*. It’s obvious in your implementation of `size()`. The *correct* implementation of `size()` would be:

```
constexpr auto size() const noexcept -> std::size_t { return m_data.size(); }
```

But *your* implementation of `size()` doesn’t actually tell me how many objects are in an instance… it just tells me the number of objects you care about, and you ignore the rest. That’s bad form.

### A static buffer may be impossible

And, as I said, it gets worse. *Much* worse.

Because, first of all, the number of active objects may not be irrelevant at all. This may not be a simple matter of mismatched counts (bad as that would be). Suppose I use your ring buffer in a low-level kernel routine (where ring buffers are *very* common) to keep track of processes, with the logic being that there can only be 32 processes open at a time, so: `ContiguousRingBuffer<process_t, 32>`. Unbeknownst to me, because it’s a hidden detail in the internals of your class, there are actually **63** processes created… and they’re all created at once… right at the start. Then I’m scratching my head about why my kernel is so slow, using so much memory, and crashing randomly.

The problem can show up in a number of ways. Let’s say I’m using the ring buffer for handles to a fixed number of resources. Like, say the system supports a maximum number of 4 open connections to something, and if you try to open a 5th, it blocks until one of those four closes. So I make a `ContiguousRingBuffer<connection_t, 4>`. Internally, it default constructs *7* connection objects, but that’s no problem, because a default-constructed connection object is closed. So my program starts, no problem, and begins to run, and eventually creates 4 connections. Then I try to create a 5th… and what I *expect* to happen is that this new connection will overwrite the oldest connection, destructing the object—and the connection is closed in the destructor—then opening the new one. It should work… except… it doesn’t. The program deadlocks. This will happen at random times, and might not even happen at all if the program never happens to need more than 4 connections in a run. It is an intermittent bug… the worst kind.

And it gets even worse. Because what if there’s some reason I can’t have objects being default constructed. If they’re simply not default-constructible at all, then the program won’t even compile. But if they *are* default-constructible, but for some reason, I never want one to be default constructed (because maybe when the class is default-constructed, it does default behaviour that I can’t have, so I always construct with a flag that disables it), then… I’m pretty well screwed, because there’s no way to stop your buffer from default constructing a bunch of objects.

This is something a lot of C++ programmers don’t understand. In particular, I see far too many people thinking that `std::vector` is just a dynamic array. They think it’s a really basic thing, and they think it’s a simple project they can attempt for practice. It’s not; it’s not any of those things; `std::vector` is *horrifyingly* complex… it’s quite easily one of the most complex classes in the entire standard library. Even though your class doesn’t use dynamic memory, it’s falling into the same trap that almost all attempts at making `std::vector` fall into.

I’m just going to tell you what you need to do to get correct behaviour… but I’m not going to give full details, and I’ll have to skip over some important stuff, because, and again, I can’t stress this enough: **WHAT YOU ARE ATTEMPTING TO DO IS ONE OF THE HARDEST THINGS TO DO IN C++** (except that, luckily, you don’t have to worry about dealing with allocators as well).

1. You can’t just use `std::array<T, ...>`, because that will automatically (default-)construct all the `T`s. You need to use `std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T) * ...>`.
2. You need to make sure that array is properly aligned.
3. When you push an item, you need to construct it in place with `construct_at()` (or `uninitialized_copy()` for multiple items). Only update `m_beg`/`m_end` if that succeeds.
4. When you pop an item, you need to destroy it with `destroy_at()` (or `destroy()` for multiple items).
5. You need to remember all the other manual memory/object management stuff, like, manually copying/moving, manually destroying everything in the destructor, and so on.

It may also be the case that it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to properly implement some of the operations of your class. For example, it may be impossible to implement copy assignment. With `std::vector`, you can implement it using a temporary buffer, and then swapping pointers if it succeeds… if it fails, you just dump the temporary buffer, and the original data is untouched. But because you’re using static memory, you don’t have the option of using a temporary buffer; you *must* destroy the existing data, so if something fails partway… you’re screwed. Even `push_back()` may be impossible to implement safely. It *may* still be possible… I’d have to think about it to be sure, because this is all really, *really* complicated stuff.

### Other stuff

Okay, let’s say you don’t care about the extra, invisible objects in your class. You only intend to use the ring buffer with trivial types, so none of the problems I mentioned really matter to you.

You should really consider making a specific iterator type for your class. `std::array<T, ...>::iterator` is just `T*`. That does the job, but is dangerous, because you can very easily mix it up with other, random pointers. A bespoke iterator leverages the type system, which is where most of the power of C++ lies.

Now, granted, if you’re stuck using C++17, then you can’t mark an iterator as contiguous. However….

If you *can* move to C++20, you absolutely should. C++20 is, *by far*, the biggest update of the language since C++11. It’s already 2022; there’s no point lingering in C++17 anymore.

And, not to put too fine a point on it… *you’re already using C++20*, whether you realize it or not. You may have tagged this code C++17… but it ain’t C++17 code. Don’t believe me? Try compiling it with a compiler that doesn’t support C++20, or explicitly set the version to C++17. You may be surprised.

And once you accept that you’re already using C++20, so much more opens up. Now you can make your iterators truly contiguous (without falling back on using `T*` as iterator). You can take advantage of concepts to make your code so much more expressive and powerful. You can use the range library to simplify and enhance safety. You can make it `constexpr` even when objects are being in-place constructed on the fly (rather than all at once when the buffer is constructed). (You can even make it `constexpr` if dynamically allocated… but you’d probably want allocator support in that case, and that makes things much more complicated.)

Finally, two last things.

Comments. Need more. You don’t need to explain the base mechanics of the code, but you do need to explain the logic of why you did things the way you did. That includes high-level stuff, like why your internal buffer is almost twice the size of what the buffer is supposed to hold… the kind of stuff that requires digging into the actual code to figure out; if someone has to sit down and carefully pore through your entire class to understand the most basic design points… that’s bad.

You also need to comment any non-obvious low-level details. For example, why, in the single item version of `push_back()`, in the `else` branch, do you swap `m_beg` and `m_end`? I honestly can’t figure this out. I’ve been scratching my head, wondering if maybe it helps with exception guarantees or something.

And last: tests. Code without tests is garbage code; utterly useless to me, and most people—no project worth its salt will accept untested code. You *should* use a proper testing framework—even a mediocre framework like GoogleTest is better than nothing—but even hacking your own tests is at least something. And best practice is to write the tests *before* the actual code: that helps you think more carefully about how you design the code.

In point of fact, you have some nasty bugs in your code that would have been trivially caught by some basic tests.

### Design review summary

1. Consider a more appropriate API. There’s nothing wrong with trying to look like a standard container, but if there’s a better interface for cases where you are using the class specifically because you want a ring buffer, then it would be nice to support that.
2. Because your class uses static allocation and pre-constructs everything, it is broken for anything but trivial types. Either:

   1. Give up on using static allocation. This will probably mean adding allocator support, and so on.
   2. Keep static allocation, but give up on pre-constructing. In other words, don’t use `std::array<T, ...>`; use a raw memory buffer (an appropriately aligned array of bytes), and placement-construct objects in it. For safety’s sake, you will probably have to require no-fail copy construction, copy assignment, move construction, *and* move assignment.
   3. Keep static allocation and pre-constructing, but give up on supporting anything but trivial types.
3. Make bespoke iterators; don’t use `T*` as the iterator type.
4. Comments!
5. Tests!
6. Embrace C++20.

## Code review

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
```

You’re missing a number of includes. At a glance, I’d say you need at least `<algorithm>` (for `std::copy()`) and `<utility>` (for `std::forward()`; well, technically `std::move()`, but we’ll get to that later).

```
  template <typename T, size_t N>
  class ContiguousRingBuffer
```

It’s `std::size_t`.

```
    using const_iterator = std::array<T, N*2-1>::const_iterator;
    using iterator = std::array<T, N*2-1>::iterator;
```

I already mentioned in the design review that you should probably make bespoke iterators.

Also, if you really want this to be C++17, you’re gonna need some `typename`s here.

Now, if you want this class to be recognized as a container, you’re going to need a bunch more aliases, like `value_type`, `size_type`, `reference`, and so on.

Another thing you might want to consider is adding `static_assert`s to constrain `T`. Exactly which ones you’ll need depend on how you want to solve the static buffer problem I discussed in the design review. (For example, you might want `static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>)`).

```
    ContiguousRingBuffer() = default;
```

You’re probably going to want to add a lot to most of the declarations in this class, mostly for the sake of efficiency. For just this default constructor, you’ll probably want:

```
    constexpr ContiguousRingBuffer() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>) = default;
```

You’ll probably want `constexpr` everywhere, and `noexcept` almost everywhere, possibly qualified.

```
    ContiguousRingBuffer(ContiguousRingBuffer&& o) = default;
    ContiguousRingBuffer& operator=(ContiguousRingBuffer const&) = default;
```

While you may not care enough to add `noexcept` to the copy operations, it’s important to make moving `noexcept` if at all possible.

(Is it possible for your type? Only if `T` is no-fail default constructible and move-assignable *or* no-fail move-constructible.)

But there’s a bug lurking here. Consider copy construction. The internal array, `m_data`, is copied from the argument’s internal array… no problem here. But `m_beg` and `m_end` are also copied… and they’re pointers to the *argument’s* internal array… not `this`’s internal array.

So what will happen is:

```
auto buf_1 = ContiguousRingBuffer<int, 5>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
auto buf_2 = buf_1;

// I want to change the first element of buf_2:
*(buf_2.begin()) = 99;

// But... the contents of the two objects are now:
//  buf_1: 99, 1, 2, 3, 4
//  buf_2:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

You see? The iterators point to the wrong data.

My advice? Rather than storing pointers, store indices. Numbers can be copied without worry. And it doesn’t really add any complexity. If you store the start index as `m_start` and the size as `m_size`, then `begin()` would just return `m_data.data() + m_start` (rather than `m_beg`), and `size()` would just return `m_size` (rather than `m_end - m_beg`).

```
    template <typename It>
    ContiguousRingBuffer(It beg, It end)
    {
      using from_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
      using to_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator>::value_type;
      static_assert(std::is_nothrow_convertible_v<from_value_type, to_value_type>,
                    "from value type must be convertible to buffer type.");

      if (static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(beg, end)) > N) {
        m_end = std::copy(std::prev(end, N), end, m_data.begin());
      }
      else {
        m_end = std::copy(beg, end, m_data.begin());
      }
    }
```

To future-proof your class, you might want to support an iterator/sentinel pair, rather than just iterator/iterator. You don’t have any other arity 2 constructors, so even in C++17, this is no problem.

Of course, if you just accept that you’re already using C++20, then you can dive right in and do:

```
template <std::input_iterator It, std::sentinel_for<It> Sen>
    requires std::indirectly_copyable<It, T*>
constexpr ContiguousRingBuffer(It beg, Sen end)
{
    std::ranges::copy(std::ranges::subrange{beg, end} | std::ranges::views::take(N), m_data.begin());
}
```

Without C++20… well, first of all, `std::is_nothrow_convertible_v` doesn’t exist.

More frustratingly, without C++20, you have an issue: your code won’t work properly with input iterators. The problem is that with input iterators, you only get one pass. Once you do `std::distance(beg, end)`, you’ve blown your one pass, so the following `std::copy()` will do nothing.

You have two options:

1. Give up, and restrict the iterator type to forward iterator or better. In C++17, you’d do that with `static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::forward_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category>)`, possibly using SFINAE.
2. Write a new algorithm that only copies *up to* a certain number of elements. I’ve had something like this in my toolkit since C++98, called `copy_upto(It, It, Out, std::ptrdiff_t)`, with multiple, optimized variants. You’d need something like that. (Or you could be lazy and just implement the algorithm ad hoc in place.)

```
    /// Initialize from any other ContinguousBuffer<S, M>
    template <typename S, size_t M>
    ContiguousRingBuffer(ContiguousRingBuffer<S, M> const& o)
      : ContiguousRingBuffer(o.cbegin(), o.cend())
    {}

    /// Initializer list constructor.
    ContiguousRingBuffer(std::initializer_list<T> init)
      : ContiguousRingBuffer(init.begin(), init.end())
    {}
```

If you make a general range constructor, you could replace both of these with it, and at the same time be able to convert *any* range.

But even if you stick with just these, you probably want to make them `explicit`, because they could be very expensive.

```
    ContiguousRingBuffer& operator=(ContiguousRingBuffer&&) = default;
    ContiguousRingBuffer& operator=(ContiguousRingBuffer const&) = default;
```

As mentioned previously, you should really try hard to make move ops `noexcept`. If you’re using static allocation, then this won’t be easy.

And, of course, you have the same bug here as in the copy/move constructors.

```
    iterator begin() { return m_beg; }
    iterator end() { return m_end; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return m_beg; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return m_end; }
```

You probably want `constexpr` and `noexcept` everywhere here.

You’ll also want `const` versions of `begin()` and `end()`.

```
    T& operator[](size_t pos) { return *std::next(m_beg, pos); }
    T const& operator[](size_t pos) const { return *std::next(m_beg, pos); }
```

This is really just a style thing, but I don’t see the point of using generic operations like `std::next()` when what you’re doing is clearly not generic. I mean, you know you have a contiguous buffer… that’s literally the whole point of the class. So you can just do `*(m_beg + pos)`. The `next()` function really just obscures what’s going on for no benefit.

```
    constexpr size_t size() const { return std::distance(m_beg, m_end); }
    constexpr auto capacity() const { return N; }
    T* data() { return &(*m_beg); }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { m_beg = m_end = m_data.begin(); }
    bool is_empty() const { return size() == 0; }
```

Gonna want `noexcept` for everything here.

Need a `const` version of `data()`.

For compatibility with standard containers, it’s `empty()`, not `is_empty()`.

You’ll also want a `max_size()` function. (I know, it’s stupid and useless, but it’s part of the container requirements.) And while we’re at it, you’ll want a `swap()` member function. (You don’t really need non-member swap, because it will be synthesized from your move ops. You can add it if you want more efficiency, though.)

You’ll also want operator `==` and `!=`, at least. Unfortunately, you can’t use defaults.

```
    void pop_back()
    {
      if (m_beg != m_end) {
        --m_end;
      }
    }
```

Note that you’re not actually removing anything from the buffer. Whatever was at the end is still there. You just moved a pointer.

```
    void push_back(T&& value)
    {
      if (m_end != m_data.end())
      {
        *(m_end++) = std::forward<T>(value);
```

I’m guessing by your use of `&&` and `std::forward()` that you intend for this function to use perfect forwarding. Unfortunately, it does not.

Perfect forwarding works thanks to two things: template parameter deduction and reference collapsing. When you write a function like this:

```
template <typename U>
void func(U&&);
```

Then when you call it normally, `U` gets deduced.

- When you call it with an lvalue `foo`, it gets deduced to `foo&` (or `foo const&`), and `(foo&)&&` reference collapses to `foo&` (or `(foo const&)&&` collapses to `foo const&`).
- When you call it with an rvalue `foo`, it gets deduced to `foo` (or `foo&&`), and `(foo)&&` reference collapses to `foo&&` (and `(foo&&)&&` collapses to `foo&&`).
- Finally, when you do `std::forward<U>()` and `U` is `foo&` or `foo const&`, `std::forward()` just expands to… nothing.
- When `U` is `foo` or `foo&&`, `std::forward()` expands to `std::move()`.

That’s how perfect forwarding works.

But when you do:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    void func(T&&);
};

auto f = foo<int>{};

f.func(...);    // <--
```

… no deduction is happening. It doesn’t matter what you write for the `...`, `T` is *always* `int`. That was set in stone in the previous line. `f.func()` will *always* take `int&&`. No deduction means no perfect forwarding.

So for any `ContiguousRingBuffer<X, N>`, `push_back()` will *always* take `X&&`. That means it always takes only rvalues.

Had you bothered to test your code, you would have noticed this immediately:

```
ContiguousRingBuffer<int, 5> buf;

buf.push_back(42);  // works with rvalues

auto i = 69;
buf.push_back(i);   // won't compile; doesn't accept lvalues
```

If you want perfect forwarding, you need to re-enable deduction. You need to do something like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class ContiguousRingBuffer
{
    // ... [snip] ...

    template <typename U>
    void push_back(U&& value)
    {
        // ... [snip] ...

        // you can use std::forward<U>(value) in here to perfect forward value
    }

    // ... [snip] ...
};

auto buf = ContiguousRingBuffer<double, 8>{};   // T is set as double

buf.push_back(3.14);    // U is deduced as (rvalue) `double`

auto val = 6.28;
buf.push_back(val);     // U is deduced as `double&`
```

You’ll probably want to constrain the deduction, though:

```
    template <typename U>
        requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<U>, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
    void push_back(U&& value)
    {
        // ... [snip] ...
    }
```

This will make sure `U` *only* gets deduced to lvalue or rvalue `T`s.

One more thing: in the `else` block:

```
        std::swap(m_beg, m_end);
        *(m_end++) = std::forward<T>(value);
```

You know that `m_end` is `m_data.end()`… but you never check what `m_beg` is. What if `m_beg` equals `m_end`? For example, if someone popped everything out of the buffer. (Note I don’t think this can happen with your current API, because your current API doesn’t actually work like a ring buffer and pop from the front. But if you add that capability, then you might get this problem.)

```
    template <typename It>
    void push_back(It beg, It end)
    {
```

This has the same problem as the constructor: it won’t work for input iterators, because the call to `std::distance(beg, end)` at the beginning will eat up the entire sequence before you get around to reading it.

I’m also not a fan of the pattern:

```
if (...)
{
    // abc
    return;
}

// xyz
```

I prefer:

```
if (...)
{
    // abc
}
else
{
    // xyz
}
```

But honestly, once functions start getting longer than ~10 lines, it’s probably time to break them up into smaller functions.

That’s probably enough of a review. I can’t dig much more deeply into the logic when there are no comments to explain what’s supposed to be going on, and no tests that can give me confidence that everything actually works. More than anything else, that’s what you really need to improve this code: comments, and tests. Once you have good, comprehensive tests, then you have the *start* of a useful library.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. I'll need to look over all of it tonight. For size() - I get your point, and yes I actually only care about begin to end. So probably name it differently??

For the use case: I get tick or bar data (from a stock or financial instrument) that I feed into the buffer and then immediately call a C indicator API on that buffer. So with something like boost::circular_buffer I would need to call `linearize()` every time

Comment: So thank you again for the review. Not completed, but here https://gist.github.com/jahnf/ba6b352a9d2b508200442a4ec40ff57c I addressed already some major issues you identified. 1) limit to trivial types; 2) use m_size and m_start instead of iterators m_beg, m_end 3) extended my doctest unit tests